# Binding Data from web service using URL and bind it with a class - ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this URL https://api.github.com/users which get a json file

this is an example or returned unbound values:

```
    [
  {
    "login": "mojombo",
    "id": 1,
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1?v=3",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/mojombo",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  {
    "login": "defunkt",
    "id": 2,
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/2?v=3",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/defunkt",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/defunkt",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/defunkt/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/defunkt/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/defunkt/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/defunkt/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/defunkt/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/defunkt/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/defunkt/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/defunkt/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/defunkt/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": true
  }
]
```

I need to binding this data to a class to use the class in my controller ... any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your class

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Avatar_url { get; set; }
    public string Gravatar_id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Html_url { get; set; }
    public string Followers_url { get; set; }
    public string Following_url { get; set; }
    public string Gists_url { get; set; }
    public string Starred_url { get; set; }
    public string Subscriptions_url { get; set; }
    public string Organizations_url { get; set; }
    public string Repos_url { get; set; }
    public string Events_url { get; set; }
    public string Received_events_url { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool Site_admin { get; set; }
}
```

And here is how you can load the data to a list of Users

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) 
{
   List<User> users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(wc.DownloadString("https://api.github.com/users"));
}
```

Comment: this lines of code
`using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) 
{
   List<User> users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(wc.DownloadString("https://api.github.com/users"));
}` 
where will write it ?

Comment: @AhmedHossamAlhansy sinsce your question was about "binding received data to a class in your controller", than the only answer i have here is "In your controller". Or wherever else you wanna handle received from  https://api.github.com/users data

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'GitHubData' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<GitHubData>'

Comment: @AhmedHossamAlhansy Then try JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GitHubData>>. I have also fixed it above

Comment: Thanks @Franky_frankly